# Estimate the Vapnik Chervonenkis dimension

Tags: machine-learning

Accourding to theorem 5 of Dr Edgard's [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/VC-Dimension-of-Neural-Networks-Sontag/48ff5cecb0f23714c50f2641e8565a3dba5eec88) can be estimated with the function $O(ρ^2)$

> Theorem 5. The class of functions computed by multilayer neural networks with binary as well as linear activations and ρ weights has VC dimension $O(ρ^2)$.

My question is how can we quantify this function, what is the function O? and how can we evaluate it?

For example if we have a neural network with 10 weights can we just say that it's VC dimension is approximated by $10 ^ 2 = 100$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sound's that I was missing some dump details : the function $O$ refers to the [big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)